# what is the best way to migrate large data from vertica to redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vertica, amazon-redshift

We have hosted vertica on AWS and the total size of the db is 500GB. 
So what is the fastest method to migrate the data from vertica to redshift ?

one approach would be
1. export the vertica data to S3
2. load the data from S3 to redshift.

Is there any better approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to get data into redshift:

1. Load it from s3
2. Load it from DynamoDB
3. Do an insert query

Insert queries, even bulk ones, are bounded by the performance of the leader node of your redshift cluster. Options #1 and #2 are better since data insertion is done in parallel to/by the compute nodes of the cluster.

update: there is a 4th option now, load through ssh: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-remote-hosts.html